# What is the python code equivalent to linux command grep -A?

Tags: python

How to print n lines after a matched string from a file using python?

**Linux Command grep**

```
 abc@xyz:~/Desktop$ grep -A 10 'foo' bar.txt
      foo
      <shippingcost>
        <amount>3.19</amount>
        <currency>EUR</currency>
      </shippingcost>
      <shippingtype>Normal</shippingtype>

      <quality>GOOD</quality> 
      <unlimitedquantity>false</unlimitedquantity>
      <isrsl>N</isrsl> 
      <stock>1</stock>
```

This command will print 10 lines after the matched string 'foo' from the file bar.txt

Using Python how to do the same thing?

**What I tried:**

```
import re
with open("bar.txt") as origin_file:
for line in origin_file:
    line= re.findall(r'foo', line)
    if line:
        print line
```

The above Python code gives this the following output:

```
abc@xyz:~/Desktop$ python grep.py
['foo']
```

Comment: At first you redefined line, resulting in the list you got printed. Also I don't see any counting of lines, so you have nothing in your code that would even go in the direction of solving the problem.

Comment: Note that there are **much** better ways to parse XML files in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file` objects such as `origin_file` are iterators. Not only can you loop through their contents using

```
for line in origin_file:
```

but also you can obtain the next item from the iterator using `next(origin_file)`.
In fact, you can call `next` on the iterator from within the `for-loop`:

```
import re

# Python 2
with open("bar.txt") as origin_file:
    for line in origin_file:
        if re.search(r'foo', line):
            print line,
            for i in range(10):
                print next(origin_file),

# in Python 3, `print` is a function not a statement
# so the code would have to be change to something like
# with open("bar.txt") as origin_file:
#     for line in origin_file:
#         if re.search(r'foo', line):
#             print(line, end='')
#             for i in range(10):
#                 print(next(origin_file), end='')
```

---

The code above will raise a `StopIteration` error if there are not 10 extra lines
after the last `foo` is found. To handle this possiblity, you could use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)
to slice off *at most* 10 items from the iterator:

```
import re
import itertools as IT

with open("bar.txt") as origin_file:
    for line in origin_file:
        if re.search(r'foo', line):
            print line, 
            for line in IT.islice(origin_file, 10):
                print line,
```

Now the code will end gracefully (without raising a `StopIteration` exception) even if there
are not 10 lines after `foo`.

Answer (score -2):

that is because you assign to line, and you don't read the lines from the file object, please change it to :

```
import re
with open("bar.txt") as origin_file:
for line in origin_file.readlines():
    found = re.findall(r'foo', line)
    if found:
        print line
```

Comment: This doesn't have the `-A` effect of printing all lines for a given period *after* a match, whether those additional lines match the target or not.